# Mocking $route in Jest (Vue)

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I've looked at the docs and found examples here, e.g.

```js
const $route = {
    fullPath: 'full/path'
}
const wrapper = mount(Component, { 
    localVue,
    mocks: {
        $route
    } 
})
```

If I console log in the Jest test `wrapper.vm.$route.fullPath = 'full/path'` but when executing the relevant code in the component it complains that `$route` is `undefined`.

This is what I'm doing in the component (building a payload for a HTTP service):

```js
pageSource: this.$route.fullPath,
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Here's how I'm running the test (and console logging in the component)

```js
    const $route = {
    fullPath: "/some/path",
    };

    describe("Form.vue validation", () => {
    it("should have submit disabled by default", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Form, {
      localVue,
      mocks: {
        $route,
      },
    });

    const submitButton = getButton(wrapper);
    expect(submitButton.attributes("disabled")).toBe("disabled");
    });


In the component:

  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$route);
  },
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. How are you "executing the relevant code"?

Comment: So I'm awaiting a call to an API service that creates a payload : await apiService(this.createPayload()); in the payload I'm setting page source from this.$route.fullPath. I've also tried console.logging this.$route in the mounted hook and it's also undefined when I run the test

Comment: Sorry, the code you added isn't enough to reproduce the problem. Can you provide a GitHub link to a reproduction?

Comment: @tony19, I moved where I was mounting the component in the test (to outside of the describe) and it started working

Answer (score 0):

For some reason moving where I mounted the test component to outside of the describe block made it work :)